# Why is this snippet O(n)?

Tags: big-o

This code snippet is suppose to have a complexity of `O(n)`. Yet, I don't understand why.

```
sum = 0;
for (k = 1; k <= n; k *= 2)  // For some arbitrary n
  for (j = 1; j <= k; j++)
    sum++;
```

Now, I understand that the outer loop by itself is `O(log n)`, so why is it that adding the inner loop makes this `O(n)`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume that *n* is a power of 2 for a moment.

The final iteration of the inner loop will run *n* times. The iteration before that will run *n*/2 times, the second-to-last iteration *n*/4 times, and so on up until the first iteration which will run once. This forms a series which sums to 2*n* − 1 total iterations. This is O(*n*).

(For example, with *n* = 16, the inner loop runs 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31 total times.)

Comment: Wouldn't that make the complexity for the entire snippet `O(n * log n)`?

Comment: No, because the inner iterations are all smaller than _n_.

Comment: I am missing a step in between. Normally, I would calculate the complexity of the outer loop, the complexity of the inner loop, and multiply the two together. With traditional for loops that are bounded by `n`, we have `n*n = n^2`. Yet, here I find that the out loop is `O(log n)`, the inner loop is less complex than `O(n)`, and then somehow the entire loop is `O(n)`. I am not sure what I a missing! I do understand the summation, but I do not understand how that leads to `O(n)`.

Comment: I think I understand now. The summation represents the number iterations in total, i.e., the inner and outer loop. So, we simply drop the constants. `2n - 1 = O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let `m = floor(lg(n))`. Then `2^m = C*n` with `1 <= C < 2`. The number `k` of steps in the inner loop goes like:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^m = 2^0, 2^1, ..., 2^m
```

Therefore the total number of operations is

```
2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^m = 2^{m+1} - 1      ; think binary
                      = 2*2^m - 1
                      = 2*C*n - 1        ; replace
                      = O(n)
```

Comment: What inspired you to introduce the constant `C` and bound it from `(1,2]`?

Comment: I didn't want to assume that `n` was a power of `2`. Hence, `lg(n) := floor(lg(n))+u = m+u` for some `u` in `[0,1)`. Thus `n = 2^{lg(n)} = 2^m*2^u` and you can take `C=2^u`, which will be in `[1,2)` because `u` is in `[0,1)`.